# IntelliJ IDEA + Scala: how to navigate to broken test easily

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I have construct like this in my Scala tests:

```scala
class ExpressionsTest extends AnyFunSpec {
  describe("simple literals") {
    describe("valid") {
      it("123") {
        runTest("123")
      }

      it("123.456") {
        runTest("123.456")
      }

      // gazillions of other tests here
    }
  }

  def runTest(ex: String) {
    // some repetitive implementation of a test
    // includes assertions, which sometimes break
  }
}
```

... and there a lot of instances of `it(...)` which provide structure of test cases, every one of them calling `runTest(...)` internally. However, when a test breaks, Intellij IDEA navigates to inner lines of `runTest(...)` (which are normally not broken), and I want it to navigate to test case itself — i.e. `it(...)` line.

Two alternative ways I'm aware of are:

- Obviously, copying `runTest(...)` into every single method — ugly and error-prone
- [Macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html), effectively doing these same embedding of `runTest(...)` into `it(...)`, which seems to be a huge overkill here

Is there any way to achieve nicer developer's experience with IntelliJ IDEA here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an implicit `Position` to the `runTest` method (which is provided by Scalatest and uses macros to give you the file/line coordinate for the error), like so:

```
import org.scalactic.source.Position
import org.scalatest.funspec.AnyFunSpec

class ExpressionsTest extends AnyFunSpec {
  describe("simple literals") {
    describe("valid") {
      it("123") {
        runTest("123")
      }

      it("123.456") {
        runTest("123.456")
      }

      // gazillions of other tests here
    }
  }

  // Passing an implicit `Position` here allows an assertion failure to
  // be reported at the caller's file and line number
  def runTest(ex: String)(implicit pos: Position) = {
    // some repetitive implementation of a test
    // includes assertions, which sometimes break
    assert(ex == "123")
  }
}
```

Running this test results in the following error:

```
"123[.456]" did not equal "123[]"
ScalaTestFailureLocation: ExpressionsTest at (ExpressionsTest.scala:12)
Expected :"123[]"
```

Clicking on the `ExpressionsTest.scala:12` through the IntelliJ IDEA UI navigates to the line that says `runTest("123.456")` (without the implicit `Position`, the result would have been that you would have been pointed to line 21, going to the `runTest` method instead).

`Position` is part of [Scalactic](https://www.scalactic.org/), a dependency of ScalaTest (created by the same author). You can read more about the `Position` class [here](https://www.scalactic.org/scaladoc/3.2.18/org/scalactic/source/Position.html).